# bash script to execute a command but with different data stored in file

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have bash script what connects to a remote server and copy a logfile to my local server with scp. On remote servers I can't copy keys or install. I have limited rights. I have some dump logs what I need to analyze so i want to copy them on local server.  This a little bit tricky cause i use expect command for password. This script is called **scp.sh** and it looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

expect -c "
    spawn scp "xxx@exemple.com:~/path/dir/some.log" /home/some.log

expect \"Password\"
send \"password\r\"
interact .
```

Now i have 2 servers (TEST and LIVE) and 2 users and i want to make it like this to execute: ./scp.sh TEST or ./scp.sh LIVE

Comment: Consider using keys rather than passwords for your ssh session. That would make your life simpler.

Comment: yeah. thats the problem cause i have only read on remote thats why i copy with scp and all the trouble with expect andetc

Answer (score 3):

You are making things more complicated for yourself by writing this as a `bash` script that calls `expect` rather than writing this as an `expect` script (or even an `env` script). This means you need to get 2 different quoting schemes to cooperate. In `tcl` you access command line parameters via the list `$argv`

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
set arg1 [lindex $argv 0]
if {$arg1 == "TEST"} {
    set user "xxx"
    set host "host1"
    set pass "testpass"
} elseif {$arg1 == "LIVE"} {
    set user "yyy"
    set host "host2"
    set pass "livepass"
} else {
    send_user "First parameter is not TEST or LIVE"
    exit 1
}

spawn scp "$user@$host:~/path/dir/some.log" /home/some.log

expect "yes/no)? " {send "yes\r" ; exp_continue} "Password"
send "$pass\r"
```

Having passwords in scripts is not great, but is probably better than passing them on the command line.

Comment: thanks this is nice. meanwhile i have 3 more servers so i need to copy data from total of 5 servers. so manually this is pretty ugly in every morning to start ssh and copy this so that is why i want to put these in cron and in morning i have in my folder all the logs. eventually i can run it manually if i need fresh data.

Answer (score 1):

So you have to pass the hostname, user and password as arguments when doing the `scp`:

```
expect -c " spawn scp "$1@$2:~/path/dir/some.log" /home/some.log
expect \"Password\" send \"$3\r\"
```

*$1* means the first argument you put after the script execution ($2 the second one and so on), so if you write:

```
./scp.sh username test password
```

Then you will send to your script:

```
expect -c " spawn scp "username@test:~/path/dir/some.log" /home/some.log
expect \"Password\" send \"password\r\"
```

Comment: user, hostname and the user's password

Comment: Just edit, try it. However note the insecure way of providing the password in plain text via CLI. The method suggested by @ClausAndersen is the correct one.

Comment: so i cant make 2 file somehow where to put this? so i do not need to pass so much data cause at some point it will be different paths